# Elementary question on stabilizer and S3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S_3$ be our group.
How can I show that $C_G(x) \text{ for }x=(1\,2\,3)$ is $\{1, (1\,2\,3),(1\,3\,2)\}$ without testing every element in $S_3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orbit of $(1\,2\,3)$ under the conjugation action has size $2$ (namely the $3$-cycles of $S_3$). By orbit-stabiliser theorem, the stabiliser has size $3$. But clearly $\langle(1\,2\,3)\rangle\in C_G(x)$, so you have found everything.

Answer (score 0):

Elements in $S_{n}$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type.